# R Convert categorical data to dummy set by other variable

Tags: r, dummy-data, upsetr

I have this data set, I put a screenshot of real data instead of a code or something.
sorry for messing up, I am a newbie here in R
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmSMF.png)

Then, I want to change the data into dummy set for "13 Source" categorical data, but it has to be summarized by "HH No". Which will look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8bWD.png)
I've tried to use to.dummy by varhandle, model.matrix but ended up messy dataset.
Could anybody help me how to deal with this?
Thanks a million in advance

Comment: Hi! It can often be useful to post a reproducible example, a great guide can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), I always find it brings more enthusiastic responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to make dummy variables from factors - here is one way to create a summary presence table.

Assume `df` is your data frame. You can use `xtabs` to start with, which will create a frequency table from your 2 columns.

By comparing to see if your values are > 0, you will get `TRUE` if > 0, and `FALSE` otherwise. Adding 0 at the end will make `TRUE` the number 1 and `FALSE` the number 0.

```
(xtabs(~ HH_No + Source, df) > 0) + 0
```

**Output**

```
     Source
HH_No Deep_well Rainwater
    1         1         1
    3         1         1
    4         0         1
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(HH_No = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 4, 4), Source = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Deep_well", 
"Rainwater"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Comment: Boom! Bro (sorry for bro-ing you) Ben.... I can't thank you enough... such an efficient- neat way to transform to dummy set...